# Computer malware injects scripts causing full of javascript errors

Tags: malware, javascript

I have a local browser application (written in php, running on usbwebserver) which runs fine on all of my users' computers except for one. When i checked the app, it seems that there have been javascript errors and when i see the console and elements (using different browsers: chrome, firefox, ie) i see that there is something that injects scripts and iframes like this

```
<script src="ner.makepre.net/sd/9050/5519.js"></script>
<iframe id="vitruciam-xdm" src="https://d8zas123151edd.cloudfront.net/cdn=1231/xd.htm" ...>
```

and alot of them.

I have searched that these links [came from a computer malware](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-ner-makepre-net-virus/) that injects scripts regardless of browser

Is there any way to get rid of them or possibly prevent them. Or should my user just clean his pc from these malware. Thanks.

Comment: Of course the user should get rid of the malware. Anything else would be ineffective and leave the user vulnerable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)